# python/mysql not saving good integers

Tags: python, mysql

there is no code required to put here.
I want to save a really long number as I am making kind of a game where score is saved.
But I tested it and put 25000000000 as the score, and in mysql it saves as 2147483647.
I also modified the limit of the integer, and set it as an integer in mysql. Any toughts?
If it is under 10 numbers it works, if it passes 10 it doesn't, even if i modified the limit

Comment: What do you mean by "modified limit of the integer"? The MySQL data type INT has always 4 bytes and is thus limited to values smaller that 2^31 for signed values.

Answer (score 3):

Use the BIGINT datatype instead.

Per the MySQL docs, the INT type only supports signed values between -2147483648 and 2147483647, whereas the BIGINT type supports signed values between -2^63 and 2^63 - 1 (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807).

Comment: Your answer would be even better with a link to the mentioned page in MySQL docs where the data types are defined.

Comment: it is enough for me to understand, it was just a matter of scrolling down and actually looking at the list